# CannotGetJDBCConnectionException when trying to run online project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I have downloaded this project from this website:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbctemplate-example/
and am using Eclipse EE and have mysql installed on my Mac computer. However, when I try to run App.java, I am getting the following error message and do not know why.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could 
not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(Data 
SourceUtils.java:80)
```

I am very new to this and am not sure if there is any additional component I have to install or if I have to make some configuration. How can I fix this exception so that the code runs?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your MySql server is running first and you have provided the correct credentials to connect to the database server. take a look at the XML bean configuration for the datasource :

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
```

Please make sure that the values of Driver-Class, username and password are for your database. if you are using maria-db database server then you need to provide the Driver-Class for it instead of standard MySql which I believe is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dependency of mysql-connector as per your mysql version.

```
<!-- MySQL Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Use this connection url to solve the problem while making connection with MySQL

```
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Your_DBName?useSSL=false" />
```

Comment: Where should I be adding the connection url?

Comment: XML bean configuration file i.e applicationContext.xml